# Permission denied on ssh access with cygwin

Tags: permissions, cygwin, openssh

I have a fresh Windows 10 family (x64) install with an Administrator account `Jean Perrin`. I installed cygwin with openssh and modified `C:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat` this way:

```
@echo off

C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
set CYGWIN=binmode ntsec
bash --login -i
```

Then, I ran into `ssh-host-config`, answered `yes` to install sshd as a service, `no` to privilege separation and let the field empty for the `value of CYGWIN for the daemon`. I asked for a new privileged account `ljp`, and checked with `netplwiz` that this account has Administrator privilege on the host.

I created the `/home/ljp` directory manually with `mkdir`.

Then I started the sshd service with `net start sshd` and was able to login with the `Jean Perrin` account:

```
$ ssh Jean\ Perrin@localhost
Jean Perrin@localhost's password:
Last login: Fri Jan 29 11:03:50 2016 from ...
```

However, when I want to connect with the `ljp` account, I get a permission error:

```
$ ssh ljp@localhost
ljp@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again
```

I tried to follow the advice found [here](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Sshd_on_Windows) and did

```
mkpasswd -l > /etc/passwd
```

but it didn't changed anything.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I connect *via* ssh with this account ?

Comment: check the logs from `sshd`. It should tell you why it failed.

Answer (score 5):

The default username format is:

```
SERVERNAME+username@SERVERNAME
```

Or edit the  `/etc/passwd` entry as shown above to make the format simpler.

Here is a site I found useful for configuring Cygwin SSH:

https://dbaportal.eu/2015/03/05/installing-openssh-cygwin-1-7-35-on-windows-2012-r2/

You can try connecting using the verbose option:

```
ssh -vvv SERVERNAME+username@SERVERNAME
```

Check that the `\home` folders exist and permissions are correct for the user.

Comment: Thank you, this was my issue